# Showing that the density of primes is zero from the inequality $\prod_{p\leq n} p\leq 4^{n-1}$

Tags: number-theory

I want to show that the density of primes is zero from the inequality
$$\prod_{p\leq n} p\leq 4^{n-1}.$$
I have already done the follwing:
$$\prod_{p\leq n}p\leq 4^{n-1}\\
        \log\left(\prod_{p\leq n}p\right)\leq(n-1)\log(4)<n\log(4)\\
        \sum_{p\leq n}\log(p)<n\log(4).$$
How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Are you familiar with summation by parts or the Stieltjes integral?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without summation by parts or Stieltjes integrals. The number of primes up to $n$ is $\sum\nolimits_{p \le n} 1$. Divide this sum into two parts and estimate the parts trivially and then by using your inequality:
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{p \le n} 1 & = \sum\limits_{p \le n} {\log p\frac{1}{{\log p}}}  = \sum\limits_{p \le \sqrt n } {\log p\frac{1}{{\log p}}}  + \sum\limits_{\sqrt n  < p \le n} {\log p\frac{1}{{\log p}}} 
\\ & \le \sum\limits_{p \le \sqrt n } {\log p\frac{1}{{\log 2}}}  + \sum\limits_{\sqrt n  < p \le n} {\log p\frac{1}{{\log \sqrt n }}}
\\ & = \frac{1}{{\log 2}}\sum\limits_{p \le \sqrt n } {\log p}  + \frac{1}{{\log \sqrt n }}\sum\limits_{\sqrt n < p \le n} {\log p}  \\ & \le \frac{1}{{\log 2}}\sum\limits_{p \le \sqrt n } {\log p}  + \frac{1}{{\log \sqrt n }}\sum\limits_{p \le n} {\log p} 
\\ & \le \frac{{\sqrt n \log 4}}{{\log 2}} + \frac{{n\log 4}}{{\log \sqrt n }} = 2\sqrt n  + 4\log 2\frac{n}{{\log n}}.
\end{align*}
Can you finish from here?

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sum_{p\leq n}\log(p)<n\log(4)$$
and $$\sum_{p\leq n}\log(p)\ge \sum_{m=1}^{\pi(n)} \log m \ge \pi(n)(\log \pi(n)-1)$$
gives that $$\frac{\pi(n)}{n} \le \frac{\log(4)}{\log \pi(n)-1}$$
there are infinitely many primes so the LHS $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$